# Why does EF5 ChangeTracker code check classes that do not inherit from IAuditableTable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been using the following code that I found recommended in many places for use with Entity Framework 5.

```
    foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                 .Where(
                      e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
                     (e.State == EntityState.Added) ||
                     (e.State == EntityState.Modified)))
    {
        IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            if (e.CreatedBy == 0) 
                e.CreatedBy = 1;
            if (e.CreatedDate == DateTime.MinValue) 
                e.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        if (e.ModifiedBy == 0) 
            e.ModifiedBy = 1;
        if (e.ModifiedDate == DateTime.MinValue) 
            e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

This works well with EF5. I simply add this:

```
public partial class Objective : AuditableTable
{
```

and have the following:

```
public abstract class AuditableTable : IAuditableTable
{
    public virtual byte[] Version { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

However. When I have a class like this:

```
public partial class Objective : AuditableTable
{
    public Objective()
    {
        this.ObjectiveDetails = new List<ObjectiveDetail>();
    }
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> ObjectiveDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Then the code does not work and I get an error on the line: `IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;` where it tries to cast the ObjectiveDetail class to an IAuditableTable:

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'Models.Core.ObjectiveDetail' to type 'Models.Core.IAuditableTable'."
```

I cannot get the check code to work unless I make the ObjectiveDetail **also inherit** from IAuditableTable or add the following additional check: `if (entry.Entity is IAuditableTable) {` to stop the method body getting run.

My question is. Why do I need to add this secondary check to the code to make it work for me and is there a better way I can make this code only work for the classes that inherit from IAuditableTable? The `e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable` seems to not work if my class contains objects that are other classes than do not implement IAuditable.

Here is my code that works:

```
foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
             .Where(
                  e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
                 (e.State == EntityState.Added) ||
                 (e.State == EntityState.Modified)))
{
    // I do not know why the following line is needed. My code will not work
    // unless I have the following line for classes that contain classes that
    // do not inherit from IAuditableTable
    if (entry.Entity is IAuditableTable) {
        IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            if (e.CreatedBy == 0) 
                e.CreatedBy = 1;
            if (e.CreatedDate == DateTime.MinValue) 
                e.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        if (e.ModifiedBy == 0) 
            e.ModifiedBy = 1;
        if (e.ModifiedDate == DateTime.MinValue) 
            e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the default precedence order of the operators && and || in the condition of the where method.

The condition you currently have has an AND and OR conditions, but you have not added brackets that would resolve the way the operators &&,|| would be resolved:

```
this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
         .Where(
              e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
             (e.State == EntityState.Added) ||
             (e.State == EntityState.Modified))
```

So by default that is being interpreted as:

```
(e.Entity is IAuditableTable && (e.State == EntityState.Added))
|| (e.State == EntityState.Modified)
```

This will include the record if (the entity was IAuditable AND added) OR was modified. So even when its not `IAuditableTable`, it will be included in the loop if the entity was modified.

For the logic that you want, you need to add brackets wrapping the || condition that checks the entity was added or modified:

```
e.Entity is IAuditableTable && 
((e.State == EntityState.Added) || (e.State == EntityState.Modified))
```

This way it will only be included if IAuditable AND (was modified OR added)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder how many other people out there also have the same problem. I have seen this same script being referenced in many places.